# Trouble finding the area of the region $y=|3x|, y=x^2-4$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm supposed to find the area of this region:

$$y=|3x|, y=x^2-4$$

So I first tried to find points of intersection:

$$|3x|=x^2-4$$
$$3|x|=x^2-4$$
$$|x|=\frac{x^2-4}{3}$$

And from here I found that $x=4, x=-4$.  So I set these as the bounds of my integral and set it up this way:

$$\int_{-4}^{4}|3x|-(x^2-4)dx$$
$$\int_{-4}^{4}(3x-x^2+4)dx$$

And when I anti-differentiated it I got:

$$\frac{3x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}+4x$$

I end up with the answer $$\frac{-32}{3}$$

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Why did you drop the absolute value in the second version of the integrand?

Comment: How do you know you are making a mistake? Is there solution given?

Comment: @User58220 I honestly don't know how to properly deal with the absolute value.

Comment: Since you have absolute values in the integral, you want to split up the integral, in this case at 0 since that's where $|3x|$ changes sign.  By symmetry, you can find $2\int_0^4 (3x-(x^2-4))dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get rid of that pesky $|3x|$ by observing that $|3x|=|3(-x)|$ and, luckily for us, $x^2-4=(-x)^2-4$. That means that both functions are symmetric about the $y$ axis (so when graphed the part for negative $x$ will have the same shape as the part for positive $x$), so
$$
\int_{-4}^4 |3x|-(x^2-4) dx = 2\int_{0}^4 |3x|-(x^2-4)dx
$$
and for $x\ge 0$ we have $|3x|=3x$, so our integral becomes
$$
2\int_{0}^4 3x-(x^2-4)dx
$$
which I have every confidence you can evaluate.

**Edit**. Not to hog the credit, I noticed that user84413 also came up with the solution while I was typing mine in.

Comment: Where did you get the $2$?

Comment: Ohhh I see... because it's symmetrical you're just getting one half of the integral and multiplying by 2.